# Java: Double machine epsilon is not the smallest x such that 1+x != 1?

Tags: java, floating-point, epsilon

I am trying to determine the `double` [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) in Java, using the definition of it being the smallest representable `double` value `x` such that `1.0 + x != 1.0`, just as in C/C++. According to wikipedia, this machine epsilon is equal to `2^-52` (with 52 being the number of `double` mantissa bits - 1).

My implementation uses the `Math.ulp()` function:

```
double eps = Math.ulp(1.0);
System.out.println("eps = " + eps);
System.out.println("eps == 2^-52? " + (eps == Math.pow(2, -52)));
```

and the results are what I expected:

```
eps = 2.220446049250313E-16
eps == 2^-52? true
```

So far, so good. However, if I check that the given `eps` is indeed the *smallest* `x` such that `1.0 + x != 1.0`, there seems to be a smaller one, aka the *previous* `double` value according to `Math.nextAfter()`:

```
double epsPred = Math.nextAfter(eps, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
System.out.println("epsPred = " + epsPred);
System.out.println("epsPred < eps? " + (epsPred < eps));
System.out.println("1.0 + epsPred == 1.0? " + (1.0 + epsPred == 1.0));
```

Which yields:

```
epsPred = 2.2204460492503128E-16
epsPred < eps? true
1.0 + epsPred == 1.0? false
```

As we see, we have a smaller than machine epsilon such which, added to 1, yields not 1, in contradiction to the definition.

So what is wrong with the commonly accepted value for machine epsilon according to this definition? Or did I miss something? I suspect another esoteric aspect of floating-point maths, but I can't see where I went wrong...

**EDIT:** Thanks to the commenters, I finally got it. I actually used the wrong definition! `eps = Math.ulp(1.0)` computes the distance to the smallest representable double > `1.0`, but -- and that's the point -- that `eps` is *not* the smallest `x` with `1.0 + x != 1.0`, but rather about *twice* that value: Adding `1.0 + Math.nextAfter(eps/2)` is rounded *up* to `1.0 + eps`.

Comment: Have you tried with `strictfp`?

Comment: Yes, `strictfp` didn't help here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> using the definition of it being the smallest representable double value x such that 1.0 + x != 1.0, just as in C/C++

This has never been the definition, not in Java and not in C and not in C++.

The definition is that the machine epsilon is the distance between one and the smallest float/double larger than one.

Your “definition” is [wrong by a factor of nearly 2](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/09/FLT_EPSILON).

Also, the absence of `strictfp` only allows a larger exponent range and should not have any impact on the empirical measurement of epsilon, since that is computed from `1.0` and its successor, each of which and the difference of which can be represented with the standard exponent range.

Comment: Is `1.0 + x != 1.0 && (1.0 + x) - 1.0 == x` an adequate definition? Or "1.0 minus (the smallest double value greater than 1.0)"?

Comment: @Random832 If you want to “compute” it, use `Math.nextAfter(1.0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) - 1.0`. The first proposal is a property that is true for many numbers including 1.0 (this is true: 1.0 + 1.0 != 1.0 && (1.0 + 1.0) - 1.0 == 1.0)

Comment: So the proposed definition (1.0 + x != 1.0) is invalid because of rounding?  Is that the case?

Comment: @BrianJ Yes. `1.0 + x` is generally inexact for values of `x` of the magnitude we are concerned with here. By contrast, though the definition by subtraction leaves this fact implicit, the distance between `0x1.0000000000001` and `0x1.0000000000000`  can be represented as a `double` and `0x1.0000000000001 - 0x1.0000000000000`, as a subtraction of close floating-point numbers, is exact and computes exactly this value.

Comment: @Pascal: I don't think there is "the" definition of machine precision, I just used one of the definitions given in the cited wikipedia article, which according to wikipedia (I'm not a numerics specialist), is the one used for C/C++. However, I don't see the difference between your definition and mine, since yours also boils down to `Math.ulp(1.0)`. Again, I may be wrong -- I just want to know *why*.

Comment: @FranzD. The wikipedia page claims that the C standard uses that definition. It does not. I **actually cite** the C standard in my blog post. Please **do check the reference for yourself**: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf (the sentence to look for is given in the blog post). The wrong definition gives the wrong result, as anyone can check for themselves (and you have). The correct definition is used in glibc. What else do you need?

Comment: What else? Maybe the ability to read more attentively :) Got it now, the Java definition is simply not correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure your experimental method / theory is sound. The documentation for the Math class states:

> For a given floating-point format, an ulp of a specific real number value is the distance between the two floating-point values bracketing that numerical value

The documentation for the `ulp` method says:

> An ulp of a double value is the positive distance between this floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude

So, if you want the smallest `eps` value such that `1.0 + eps != 1.0`, your eps really should generally be *less than* `Math.ulp(1.0)`, since at least for any value greater than `Math.ulp(1.0) / 2`, the result will be rounded up.

I think the smallest such value will be given by `Math.nextAfter(eps/2, 1.0)`.

Comment: The mathematical ulp(x) is defined for any real x, so for most values of x, it doesn't matter whether the definition has ≤ or <. It is not generally agreed on what ulp(x) means when x is a power of two (the case for which it would matter whether it's ≤ < or < ≤). There is a quite thorough treatment in http://www.ens-lyon.fr/LIP/Pub/Rapports/RR/RR2005/RR2005-09.pdf

Comment: @davmac: I'm also not sure that my approach is sound, that's why I asked :) But I don't understand: Why isn't `ulp(1.0)`, "the positive distance between 1.0 and the double next larger in magnitude", the smallest value such that `1.0 + eps != 1.0`? There shouldn't be any smaller value with that property, as then `ulp(1.0)` *isn't* the distance to the *next* larger double. But, as @Pascal said, there doesn't seem to be a general definition of `ulp(1.0)`, so maybe my problem lies here. Still I don't get it...

Comment: @FranzD. The value given by the “definition” as “smallest representable double value x such that 1.0 + x != 1.0” is not a power of two, so it is not the result of the ulp function for any definition of the mathematical ulp, nor for the Java method named `ulp`.

Comment: @Pascal: Huh? Who said ulp(x) returns only powers of two? I only said that the input x = 1.0 is a power of two, so ulp's results may be dubious.

Comment: @FranzD. I said that ulp returns powers of two. You do not have to believe me. Did you read http://www.ens-lyon.fr/LIP/Pub/Rapports/RR/RR2005/RR2005-09.pdf ?

Comment: I believe you, but I hadn't read the link... It always amazes me how complex floating-point computation is, if you look closer.

Comment: @FranzD. "I don't understand: Why isn't ulp(1.0), "the positive distance between 1.0 and the double next larger in magnitude", the smallest value such that 1.0 + eps != 1.0?" - because of rounding. (This is hinted at in my answer). `ulp` returns the difference between a value and the next largest (or smallest) value. But, you can take the original value, and add a smaller-than-ulp value, and the result might be _closer_ to the next-largest value than it was to the original value, and so it will be rounded up.

Comment: Yeah, got my problem now and summarized it in an edit to the question. Thank you all for your patience and insight.

Answer (score 0):

In fairness to the OP, the definition he gives for machine epsilon is the same one I learned in Numerical Methods lo these many years ago. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), as of the date of this comment, both definitions are in widespread use. The two definitions may be either equivalent, or may differ by a factor of two, depending on whether the computer is using rounding or truncation.